# Why app breaks in onCreate() on line setVisibility(View.GONE)?

Tags: android, visibility

I want to dynamically hide some elements if a certain condition is met. I use this code to hide a `TextView`

```
if (something) {
            //do something
        } else {
            myTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I use this code in `onCreate`.

However, the app breaks on the line where `View.GONE` is.

Why does it happen? Is it not allowed to hide elements in onCreate? If this is true, where should I use this code?

To clarify, I want to hide them before the `Activity` loads. The same code in the button's click event does not break the app.

Comment: Post the Stacktrace and LogCat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextView myTextView might be null, 
you have to reference it before you use it.
Usually you do this via

```
myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextviewid)
```

As said by Lukas Knuth, check and post your Stracktrace. You should see
a NullPointerException there.

Comment: No need for stacktrace. I was initializing TextView inside for part of the condition. That's why it was breaking. Just an oversight. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make your view `visibility="gone"` in your xml.... And check particular condition..

```
if(cond)
{
myTextViewmyTextView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
```

Also check id in xml and findViewById() both should be same.... IF myTextView id is not referenced in your code it shows:Null Pointer Exception